# [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am learning vuejs but I can't find a proper answer.  When i am clicking on edit age button or change my name button i am getting below error.

[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "myName"

[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "userAge"

Code is here.

https://codesandbox.io/s/k2197nr4o3

Please let me know what is wrong in this code.

Answer (score 11):

It is obvious that you are trying to change directly the props properties.

For example:

```
props: { name: 'something' }
methods: { 
 change_name(new_name) {
   this.name = new_name
 }
}
```

This is not recommended and it may lead on reactivity lack.

As solution, you can use parent child communication. So whenever you want to change a prop, just emit an event to the parent component. So the above example should be:

```
props: { name: 'something' }
methods: { 
 change_name(new_name) {
   this.$emit('name-updated', new_name)
 }
}
```

And on the parent component listen to that event to change the prop you are passing:

`<child-component :name="name" @name-updated="name = $event" />`

Or my favorite way is to use [.sync](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) modifier.So the parent component should be:

`<child-component :name.sync="name" />`

and the method on the child component:

```
 change_name(new_name) {
   this.$emit('update:name', new_name)
 }
```

If the components do not have parent-child relation take a look to [Vue.js Event Bus](https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860) or [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org)

Comment: i am trying this solution but not getting proper solution. please help me.

Comment: Tried the last method but seems still to be giving the same error.

Comment: Its all working well but for some reason the name doesn't transfer from new_name to event. when i hard coded it does work, any idea why ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a computed value instead. For example in your UserEdit.vue:

In your template:

```
<p>User Age: {{ computedUserAge }}</p>
```

In your script:

```
methods: {
    editAge() {
        this.computedUserAge = 30;
    }
},
computed: {
    computedUserAge: {
      get() {
        return this.userAge;
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("ageWasEdited", v);
      }
    }
}
```